# verbatim environment fails on ' and `?

Tags: verbatim

```
\begin{verbatim}  
   infile 'dir_location\filename.csv' delimiter=",";  
\end{verbatim}
```

throws an error on the first `'`.

What the H?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Works just fine for me, when inserting your snippet after `\begin{document}`. Do you have more stuff going on in your source?

Comment: Also, sometimes, deleting the .aux file can help clear things up.

Comment: It is also working with me

Comment: Please add the *complete* first error message.

Comment: Deleted the .aux-- no dice.  

  
Here's the error:  
! Undefined control sequence.  
infile '  
                dir_location\filename.csv' delimiter=",";  
l.362 \end{verbatim}  
  
I was able to identify the problem is in Sweave.sty.  Will repost if I can't find other info.  Thanks all for your help.