# Sweave.sty causing error in verbatim environment?

Tags: verbatim, sweave

folks--

The following throws an error, shown below

```
\documentclass{book}  
\usepackage{Sweave}  

\begin{document}  

\begin{verbatim}  
data ds;  
   infile 'dir_location\filename.csv" delimiter=",";  
   input varname1 ... varnamek;  
run;  
\end{verbatim}  

\end{document}
```

**Error:**

```
! Undefined control sequence.  
infile '  
                dir_location\filename.csv' delimiter=",";  
l.362 \end{verbatim}
```

Occurs with any ' or ` character in verbatim environments.

Any idea what could be causing this?  Or a workaround?

Thanks!

Comment: I believe this has been asked before.  I can't remember the thread but I recall seeing it recently.  You should just edit you OP: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121051/verbatim-environment-fails-on-and?rq=1 then start a new one.

Answer (score 2):

I do not have any problems with your MWE and my version of `Sweave.sty`, but I remember some problems years ago.  The option `noae` as in `\usepackage[noae]{Sweave}` then helped.

Perhaps you might want to upgrade `Sweave.sty` or `ae`.

Comment: That did it!  Thanks a million, Boris!  I'll also seek out a newer version of Sweave.sty.